# Added key locally using ssh-add work on remote

Tags: ssh, remote

I would like to be able to use locally added ssh key to agent on remote host without calling ssh-add on remote.

```
john@john-VirtualBox:~$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/ansusersu_rsa
Enter passphrase for /home/john/.ssh/ansusersu_rsa: 
Identity added: /home/john/.ssh/ansusersu_rsa (ansusersu@galaxy)
john@john-VirtualBox:~$ ssh ansusersu@192.168.0.3 'sudo whoami'
root
john@john-VirtualBox:~$ ssh ansusersu@192.168.0.2 'sudo whoami'
root
john@john-VirtualBox:~$ ssh ansusersu@192.168.0.3 'ssh ansusersu@192.168.0.2 '"'"'sudo whoami'"'"''
Host key verification failed.
```

What I mean, after I loaded key to agent I'm able to connect to both hosts 192.168.0.3 & 192.168.0.2. When I execute a command on 192.168.0.3 in there I do some access to 192.168.0.2 and now it shows "Host key verification failed", but I would like to make it work. Is it possible to make it work?
In reality I need to do on 192.168.0.3 rsync of a folder from 192.168.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Host key verification failed.

says that the authenticity of server `192.168.0.2` was not verified, because it's host key is not in the `known_hosts` of `192.168.0.3`. So first of call, manually connect to the `192.168.0.3` and from there to `192.168.0.2` and verify the host key.

Then you can use `ssh-agent` forwarding (`-A` switch):

```
ssh -A ansusersu@192.168.0.3 'ssh ansusersu@192.168.0.2 sudo whoami'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was about to answer my question.
Another option to "-A" is to add into ~/.ssh/config 2 lines: "Host * ForwardAgent yes
". But that option is not good from security point

Comment: Yes, enabling that for all the hosts is not a good idea.